# Connecting to Web API while debugging an Android app - Xamarin

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I am trying to connect to an external Web API on my local workstation while debugging my android application using Xamarin.

I can connect to the API URL using the server's IP address, but I cannot connect to the API URL using the website domain name.

I have checked the INTERNET under the configuration properties in the Android manifest to allow my application to connect to the internet.

What do I need to do to have my Android application to connect to the Web API using the website domain name?

Comment: Are you sure you added the internet permission in the android manifest? Check also if the emulator is connect with internet. Put here your log application.

Comment: How do I check my emulator to verify it has internet connectivity?  For my android project, i went project properties->Android Manifest->configuration properties->check the "Internet" checkbox

Comment: if it can connect via IP, but not domain, then it has connectivity, but sounds like there is just a DNS issue.